# Replacing improper date in a specific field

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table `notes`. In it, a date somehow became corrupt and I need to fix it.  When I did a query to find it, I can isolate the specific instance with other data but not sure if what I think the answer is will mess it up worse.

Here is the data I used to verify the specific instance:

```
date_service   "20104-02-17 00:00:00" -- as you can see the year is wrong
date_creation  "2014-02-17 10:12:59.951"
zrud_client    "A6150528-4192-4894-8C2D-251C886B0093"
zzud_note      "77660C9E-4672-4864-A9E0-D32A60757E2C"
```

I think I can correct it by using the following.  Will this work?

```
UPDATE TABLE notes
SET date_service = replace (date_service, '20104-02-17 00:00:00', '2014-02-17 10:12:59.951')
```

Comment: I think you'd be safer to add the other information in a where clause, to ensure you only update the one record.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed solution might work, but it's definitely not the way to approach this problem.

What it will do is go through **every row in the table**, get its `date_service` column, run some string manipulation, and save the value back. Clearly, if there is only one (or a handful) of dates to fix, this is very inefficient.

The way to think with SQL is, first, which rows do you want to look at, and second, what do you want to do with them.

If there is only that specific corrupted string, selecting the rows is easy, and easy to read: `WHERE date_service =  '20104-02-17 00:00:00'`. Since we're being specific with the rows, the what to do is easy too: `SET date_service =  '2014-02-17 00:00:00'`. So the whole statement is:

```
UPDATE notes
SET date_service =  '2014-02-17 00:00:00'
WHERE date_service =  '20104-02-17 00:00:00'
```

This also allows us to see if there are other bad values we can fix at the same time, by selecting rows with similar date values. How to do this depends if your dates are just stored as strings, or as a `timestamp` column type. If they're just strings, you can do a prefix match like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM notes
WHERE date_service LIKE '20104-%'
```

If it's a timestamp column, you'd need to look for dates way in the future, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM notes
WHERE date_service > '20100-01-01 00:00'
```

Once you get the WHERE clause right and can see that you're targeting the right rows, you can use it to write a more general update, using a more general replacement than the one in your question, e.g.

```
UPDATE notes
SET date_service = replace(date_service, '20104-', '2014-')
WHERE date_service LIKE '20104-%'
```

Comment: I think the plan was to set it to `'2014-02-17 10:12:59.951'`. Strictly speaking, it might be better to base the `WHERE` condition on the PK, but with a case like this, it won't matter, so d'accord otherwise.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ah, yes, I missed that. I was leading up to suggesting a more general query anyway, and hit save in case I messed something up or a faster typer overtook me. If only one row needs updating then yes, finding the PK and updating on that would be a better habit.